# Different images fade in/out depending on where mouse is on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to see if there's a way, using jQuery or Javascript, to have four different images, each one separately fading in quickly (say 1000ms) and out slowly (say 4000ms) depending on whether the mouse is in the top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right quadrant, with the images fading in/out in the corresponding quadrant but more towards the center (so if all images are faded in at the same time, they partially overlap). The images should be behind everything in the body tag but visible in html-rendered white space and anything opaque. Is this possible?

Comment: paste your html so tat it would b precise to work out.

Comment: There's no html, just a concept at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){

    var width=$(window).width();
    var height =$(window).height();
    $('.image_container').css('marginLeft',''+((width-400)/2)+'px');
    $('.image_container').css('marginTop',''+((height-400)/2)+'px');


    $(".conner_boxes").mouseenter(function(){
        $('.image_container > img').eq($(this).index()).animate({opacity:.2});
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $('.image_container > img').eq($(this).index()).animate({opacity:1});
    });                      


});
```

Is this the way you want it ? http://jsfiddle.net/Aveendra/hp8xP/ check the fiddle

Comment: I'm going to try this out. Where in the html doc does the JavaScript in your fiddle need to go? Is any other code needed to make it work (script tags, anonymous function for example)?

Comment: All you have to do is,use the same code exactly as there in the fiddle. I ll also add some comments in the fiddle. So it will make it easier to understand.